# MySql PDO beginning a transaction and passing it to objects

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Will this work? I'd test it but I don't know how to crash things half way though.

```
$db = DB::getDB();
try{
    $db->begintransaction();
    Invoice::saveInvoice($info, $db);
    InvoiceDetails::saveDetails($moreInfo, $db);
    $db->commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    $db->rollback();
}
```

And if it does work is there anything that could bite me in the butt besides doing something that causes a implicit commit?

Comment: You're missing the exception in your `catch` statement but other than that, I'd say this is fine. To crash things, just throw an exception, eg `throw new Exception('KA-BLAM!');`

Comment: @Phil I added the catching the exception, that's why I use an IDE or I wouldn't get a line of code to run. I didn't even think about the KA-BLAM exception, good thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I'd do is fix up your exception handling. For example

```
catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Doing this lets you safely rollback the transaction as well as letting the error bubble up further in your application.

You could even wrap the inner exception (which will probably be a `PDOException`) with one of your choosing, eg

```
$db->rollback();
throw new RuntimeException('Error saving invoice details', 0, $e);
```

To *"crash things half way though"*, simply throw an exception within one of your `save*` methods, eg

```
throw new Exception('KA-BLAM!');
```

Comment: Got it Phil. Thanks! Although if I start having data integrity issues I'm pointing them right at you and saying 'Phil said I could do it that way'